# Incompatible types in assignment in inheritance - Mypy error

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

In my project my Mypy is haunting me over some inheritance, and I can't find a reason why in some cases it does not complain about the error:

```py
note: In class "Cat":
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Dict[str, Any]", base class "Animal" defined the type as "None")
```

and does not for the `Dog`, code example:

```py
class Animal:
  attributes = None

  def __init__(self):
    if attributes is None:
      raise NotImplementedExcepton


class Cat(Animal):
  attributes = {
    'fur': 'black',
    'sound': 'meow',
  }

class Dog(Animal):
  attributes = {
    'fur': 'brown',
    'sound': 'woof',
  }
```

Comment: "in some cases it does not complain" In which cases does it not complain? Are these cases actually desirable? Why do you assign ``attributes = None`` in the first place, instead of just annotating as e.g. ``attributes: Dict[str, Any]``?

Comment: I'll edit, but basically it looks exactly the same...

Comment: How do i annotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` can be `None` as seen in `Animal`, so you define it as `Optional`. Then you also define what type of `attributes` might be.

```
from typing import Dict, Optional


class Animal:
    attributes: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.attributes is None:
            raise Exception


class Cat(Animal):
    attributes = {
        'fur': 'black',
        'sound': 'meow',
    }
```

This won't raise any mypy errors.

Comment: What if I have `attributes` defined as `attributes: Widget` and in `Cat` class i have `attributes: SomeOtherWidget` where `SomeOtherWidget(Widget)` inherits `Widget`? How to resolve this?

Comment: Then it's still `attributes: Widget`.

Comment: But I am getting the error: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "type[HTMLWidgetTrackingTrump]", base class "BaseHTMLField" defined the type as "Widget")`